# Image is not displayed in html via camera native

Tags: ionic3, android-camera

I'm trying to create an app that uses camera. I got the camera working and stored in the album but the problem is, the image taken doesn't appear in the html. I don't know what I did wrong.

```
 camera.html
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="capture()">
                  <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
                  </button> 
                 <p>Picture</p>
              <img [src]="captureDataUrl"  *ngIf="captureDataUrl"/>

    camera.ts
    export class cameraPage{
    captureDataUrl: string;



     capture() {
            const cameraOptions: CameraOptions = {
              quality: 50,
              encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
              correctOrientation: true,
              saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
              targetWidth: 100,
              targetHeight: 100
            };

            this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions).then((imageData) => {
              // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
              // If it's base64:
              this.captureDataUrl =  imageData;
            }, (err) => {
              // Handle error
            });
          }
        }
```

I did follow the instruction on https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/ but its still not appearing in the html. im trying to save locally. not using firebase. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If its base64 response then use,

**this.captureDataUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;**

If u want response as base64 format, then camera option as

**destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL**